# Is there a way in R to visually show which attribute causes clustering in a hierarchical cluster?

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

The hierarchical cluster will group items that are most similar, based on the similarity matrix. But how can you go about determining what about a cluster is similar, and how can you visually show that?

Consider the following code:

```
data(USArrests)
# Compute distances and hierarchical clustering
dd <- dist(scale(USArrests), method = "euclidean")
hc <- hclust(dd, method = "ward.D2")
plot(hc, hang = -1, cex = 0.6)
```

The table in itself contains information about each state and murder rates, assault rates, population and so on (I'll refer to each column as an attribute). When applying the cluster to the data, we see states like Alabama, Louisiana, Georgia and Tennessee cluster together.

How can i go about determining which attribute causes some states to cluster? For instance, it could be that the four states mentioned above each have a really high assault rate and low murder rate, and similar urban pop. But aside from calculating the deviation of each attribute for each cluster, is there an easier way i can go about determining that, and most importantly visualizing it?

Answer (score 0):

Doing a K-means cluster analysis is probably what you're looking for. Here's an article with using the exact example you have on how to use it to partition those areas of similarity in each one with the visualization.

https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/k-means-clustering-in-r-algorith-and-practical-examples/

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are asking the wrong question. In order for states to be in the same cluster, they must be somewhat similar in *all* dimensions. I think a better question would be why don't other states fall in the same cluster? What is different about the other states?  You only have four dimensions here so it is easy to just look at all dimensions. I will use your example of Alabama, Louisiana, Georgia and Tennessee.

```
n = 10
CL = cutree(hc, n)
which(CL ==1)
  Alabama   Georgia Louisiana Tennessee 
        1        10        18        42 

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(USArrests[,2:3], pch=20, col=rainbow(n, end=0.75)[CL])
plot(USArrests[,c(1,4)], pch=20, col=rainbow(n, end=0.75)[CL])
legend("topleft", legend=1:n, pch=20, col=rainbow(n, end=0.75), bty="n")
```

[image: USArrests]

Now we can compare different clusters. For example, cluster 10 (Purple) is completely different.

```
which(CL ==10)
North Dakota  South Dakota       Vermont West Virginia 
         34            41            45            48
```

Cluster 10 is low in all four dimensions, whereas cluster 1  has a rather high murder rate and is somewhat higher in all three other dimensions. Not very similar.

Cluster 9 (Dark Blue).

```
which(CL ==9)
   Mississippi North Carolina South Carolina 
            24             33             40
```

These are other deep south states that we might expect to be more similar to cluster 1. Indeed, they are very similar in the rape and murder dimensions. The clusters overlap. Yet they are different clusters because of the other dimensions. Cluster 9 has a lower urban population but a higher assault rate.

Presumably, the points in any one cluster are similar. For any pair of groups, you can look at the two in these plots and see why they are different.